# How can I troubleshoot why LIRC's sent signal doesn't power on devices?

Tags: pi-3, led, raspbian-stretch, lirc

I am trying to setup IR remote control with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. OS - Raspbian stretch. The PI pins schema [is like that](http://www.piddlerintheroot.com/ir-blaster-lirc/). The LIRC setup is outdated, so I found some other manuals and combined them.

So what I have right now, I see that some signals are being send (tried to replace IR red with the RED one and it was blinking, additionally checked IR led on camera and saw it flashing). But I can't control any device. I even put 2 IR LEDs together and that didn't help either.

How can I figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you monitor the commands you are sending and compare them to the commands received from a unit known to work.

You can use my [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) to monitor the pulses.  An alternative terminal based script is [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py).

Both programs require the pigpio daemon to be running (`sudo pigpiod`).

It's also worth checking to see if the range is the problem, i.e. place the receiver close to the transmitter.